# Not able to parse String date of format IST and GMT format

Tags: android, locale, simpledateformat

Not able to parse String date `Sun Dec 06 11:15:00 IST 2015` using `SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy")` when I use `Locale.ENGLISH` in `SimpleDateFormat` without `Locale.ENGLISH` working but

Not able parse when app language changes to non-English language like `Marathi/Hindi`.

I am able to parce other string date like `10 12 2018` to `dd MM yyyy` but not above format.

**Facing issue on `Lollipop and kit-kat` devices.** when I change `Locale` to non-English language.

**minSdkVersion 16 and targetSdkVersion 27**

1.Tried following solutions.

> EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy ,EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy ,DateFormat etc

```
String tDueDate="Sun Dec 06 11:15:00 IST 2015"; 
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date dt = sdf.parse(tDueDate);
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        return sdf.format(dt);
```

> **Sat Oct 03 00:00:00 IST 2018**
>   12-12 13:16:33.733 17653-17653/com.smartsms.organizer.events W/System.err: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sat Oct 03 00:00:00 IST 2018" (at offset 20)
>   12-12 13:16:33.733 17653-17653/com.smartsms.organizer.events W/System.err:     at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:555)
>   12-12 13:16:33.733 17653-17653/com.smartsms.organizer.events W/System.err:     at com.smartsms.util.EventsUtil.returnDateInDateFormat(EventsUtil.java:750)
>   12-12 13:16:33.733 17653-17653/com.smartsms.organizer.events W/System.err:     at com.smartsms.fragment.EventsFragmentNew$MyTask.onPostExecute(EventsFragmentNew.java:1397)
>   12-12 13:16:33.733 17653-17653/com.smartsms.organizer.events W/System.err:     at com.smartsms.fragment.EventsFragmentNew$MyTask.onPostExecute(EventsFragmentNew.java:1295)
>   12-12 13:16:33.733 17653-17653/com.smartsms.organizer.events W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
>   12-12 13:16:33.733 17653-17653/com.smartsms.organizer.events W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
>   12-12 13:16:33.733 17653-17653/com.smartsms.organizer.events W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
>   12-12 13:16:33.733 17653-17653/com.smartsms.organizer.events W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   12-12 13:16:33.733 17653-17653/com.smartsms.organizer.events W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   12-12 13:16:33.733 17653-17653/com.smartsms.organizer.events W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5111)
>   12-12 13:16:33.733 17653-17653/com.smartsms.organizer.events W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   12-12 13:16:33.733 17653-17653/com.smartsms.organizer.events W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   12-12 13:16:33.733 17653-17653/com.smartsms.organizer.events W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:806)
>   12-12 13:16:33.733 17653-17653/com.smartsms.organizer.events W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
>   12-12 13:16:33.733 17653-17653/com.smartsms.organizer.events W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   12-12 13:16:33.733 17653-17653/com.smartsms.organizer.events

Activitylocale: **en_US**

Comment: Which version of `SimpleDateFormat` are you using `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` or `android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat`?

Comment: @MorrisonChang `java.text.SimpleDateFormat;` format I am targeting minimum of  `version 16`

Comment: Have you tried `Locale.US` instead. Suggested by [the Android documentation on Locale - Be wary of the default locale](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale#unicode-localelanguage-extension)

Comment: @MorrisonChang yes I have tried Having issue on `kitkat and lollipop` rest its working

Comment: Provide a working sample include source date string which isn't parsing/generates error on kitkat/lollipop and is working on later versions. Also add your test steps like using kitkat emulator switch language to x.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to parse a string from `Date.toString`? Could you just avoid the `toString` call and instead get hold of the original `Date` object?

Comment: @OleV.V. thanks I have tried with Date Object and `Calendar` solved my problem

Comment: FWIW I tried if I could reproduce the `ParseExcepttion` on my desktop Java 7 somehow, but was unable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for answer why its not able to parce String `Sun Dec 06 11:15:00 IST 2015 using SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy")` other date formats like String date `01 10 2018` this with `dd MM YYYY` format able to parce but not above. So

I have tried this alternative way to get respective date format.

Hope this will help some one

> **value** is date object

```
Date date   = d.parse(value);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(date);
int dd = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int mmm = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
int yyyy = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

String dateString = "" + dd + "-" + mmm + "-" + yyyy;
```

Comment: Removing the z in the format worked for me. Not sure why! If anybody knows, please help.

Answer (score 0):

try with change code like

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        Date dt = sdf.parse(tDueDate);
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        return sdf.format(dt);
```

Comment: I have tried but on its not working on some `kitkat and lollipop`  device getting unable to parce

Answer (score 0):

you could have a try like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

change to :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat ("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'IST' yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String dateStr = "Sun Dec 06 11:15:00 IST 2015";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(dateStr);
System.out.println(date);
```